# Why does UWP render differently on different devices? Alignment is off

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Here's my application on my Dell Monitor:

[image]

Here's the exact same application, drawn seconds after moving it to my laptop (Yoga) monitor:

[image]

Notice that in the right hand image of the second picture the columns don't align with their headers.

Any clues where to start looking for a solution to this?

Comment: Does each display have the same DPI settings?

Comment: If you mean scaling, the answer is no (Windows 10 doesn't give the DPI, just the scale).  The first picture was at 100%, the second was at %125.  When I switched the second monitor to 100%, I got the pictures to line up.  Where does that leave me?  I can't tell my customers to change the DPI on their monitors so the columns line up.

Comment: Alternatively, if I change the first monitor to %125, I get the same misalignment on both screens.  Definitely appears related to the scaling.  I don't round or snap the pixels anywhere, so again, I'm not sure how that helps me.

Comment: This may related to  UWP  [Effective pixels and scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro) The render system manage this based on your screen and scale. It's hard to say how you can adjust all the situation. For example, maybe your UI extend its width to the end of the screen and then the system caculate and changed the behavior of your app be default.

Answer (score 1):

Credit should go to Barry Wang for recognizing the issue.  The article he references had the (unintuitive) solution: the boundaries of controls need to be evenly divisible by 4.  Here's the control, magnification of 125%, with column boundaries on multiples of 10:

[image]

Here's the exact same control, magnification of 125%, with column boundaries on multiples of 4:

[image]

Thank you Barry.

Comment: Wow. Glad to know that and thanks for sharing the valuable answer!